# HLS Stream OneTimePassword (GetHLSToken from 511nj.org)

Tags: http, access-token, http-live-streaming

For research purposes, we analyzed and extracted large-scale traffic data from 511nj cameras. Starting from 2020, it adds an OTP(one-time password) to the video link, which is requested by the website API: https://511nj.org/api/client/camera/getHlsToken?Id=2&rnd=202205281151, as observed from the network traffic. However, the website itself gets a response of 200 with a valid token, while accessing it by myself gets a response of 401, which indicates an unauthorized request. What makes me confused is why I can get the camera feed with the OTP through the web site, but can't access the API. Is there a solution?

Failed attempt:

```
requests.get('https://511nj.org/api/client/camera/getHlsToken?Id=2&rnd='+datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')).json()
```

20220601 Update: Modification has been made based on @Brad 's comment. However, the error message now turns into "An error has occurred". Please help!

```
def GetOTP():
    import requests
    import json
    import datetime
    Now = datetime.datetime.now()
    DT = Now.strftime('%Y%m%d%I%M%S')
    DT24 = Now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')
    Enigma = dict(zip(map(str,range(0,10)),('2','1','*','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')))
    cookies = {
        'ReloadVersion': '112',
        '_ga': 'GA1.2.335422978.1653768841',
        '_gid': 'GA1.2.721252567.1653768841',
    }
    
    headers = {
        'authority': '511nj.org',
        'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'referer': 'https://511nj.org/Scripts/Directives/HLSPlayer.html?v=V223',
        'responsetype': "".join([Enigma[key] for key in DT[4:6]])+'$'.join([Enigma[key] for key in DT[6:8]])+'$'.join([Enigma[key] for key in DT[:4]])+'#'+Enigma[DT[9]]+"!".join([Enigma[key] for key in DT[10:12]])+"!"+DT[-2:]+"#PK",
        'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="102", "Google Chrome";v="102"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.61 Safari/537.36',
    }
    
    params = {
        'Id': '2',
        'rnd': DT24,
    }

    Response = requests.get('https://511nj.org/api/client/camera/getHlsToken?Id=2&rnd='+DT24, headers=headers,cookies=cookies,params=params).json()

    print("".join([Enigma[key] for key in DT[4:6]])+'$'+''.join([Enigma[key] for key in DT[6:8]])+'$'+''.join([Enigma[key] for key in DT[:4]])+'#'+Enigma[DT[9]]+"!"+''.join([Enigma[key] for key in DT[10:12]])+"!"+DT[-2:]+"#PK")
    print(params['rnd'])
    print(Response)
    return Response['Data']
```

Comment: The key is in the request headers.  There is a `ResponseType` header in which they've put in an obfuscated timestamp from the server and the client.  I don't know why they do this... it provides no security, the streams are public, and seems to be a hassle for everyone, but yeah, there it is.  Check your browser's developer tools to see the source code for generating those obfuscated timestamps.

Comment: @Brad I updated the code, which still doesn't work. I think that the direction is correct but deep down some details are not correct in either cookies or headers...Any ideas?